# JavaScript closures. Access in loop to current i, j variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I  try to dynamically generate `<table>` with jQuery and I want to set click handlers to each cell, so when cell clicked the popup will appear with current index of cell. How I can access to CURRENT `i` and `j` variables in loop?

```
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
      for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
          var td = $('<td></td>');
          td.click(function() {
            alert(i + ' ' + j);  // here I want to access to CURRENT i, j variables
          })
          td.appendTo(tr);
      }
  }
```

Comment: I'd delegate event to table instead

Comment: FYI, you can always get the index of table rows and cells right from the element. So in your handler, you could do `this.cellIndex` to get the index for the `<td>`. For the row, you could do `this.parentNode.rowIndex` as long as your loop indices align with the row indices.

Comment: @user2736012 ah, thanks for the reminder about `.cellIndex` and `.rowIndex` - I had forgetten that tables have those, whereas other elements require you to count back through the siblings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers mostly explain how to fix the closure problem, although such methods are not particularly memory efficient since they end up creating a new closure for each possible combination of `i` and `j`.

However, since you're using jQuery you have a number of other options available to you:

#### Pass `data` parameters to the `.on` call

```
td.on('click', { i: i, j: j }, function(event) {
    var i = event.data.i;
    var j = event.data.j;
    alert(i + ' ' + j);
});
```

The `i` and `j` values as you can see above will be available in `event.data`

#### Use `$.each` to iterate instead of a `for`

```
$.each(Array(5), function(i) {
    // i is already bound here because it's a function parameter
    $.each(Array(5), function(j) {
        // and j available here
        td.on('click', ...);
    });
});
```

#### Use event delegation instead of a per-element handler

```
$('#myTable').on('click', 'td', function() {
    // use jQuery methods to determine the index, e.g.
    var j = this.cellIndex
    var i = this.parentNode.rowIndex
    ...
});
```

which is more efficient than binding a separate handler to each `<td>` individually.

#### and more generically, use `.data()` to store per-cell information

You can store data values directly on elements, which would work very well if you wanted to retrieve values other than the cell and row indexes:

```
td = $('<td>').data({i: i, j: j});
```

and then extract these row and column values directly from the clicked element's `.data`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
    for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        $('<td></td>').data({i: i, j: j}).appendTo(tr);
        td.appendTo(tr);
    }
}

$('#myTable').on('click', 'td', function() {
    var data = $(this).data();
    var i = data.i;
    var j = data.j;
    alert(i + ' ' + j);
});
```

Comment: +1 for providing great alternatives, good advice, and well-written explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Introducing them into a new scope will capture their current value:

```
(function(i, j) {
    td.click(function() {
        alert(i + ' ' + j);  // here I want to access to CURRENT i, j variables
    });
})(i, j);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new scope for the 'current' value of `(i, j)` by executing a function inside the loop like this

```
td.click((function (i, j) {
    return function (event) {
        console.log(i, j);
    }
})(i, j));
```

You could make this a little more succinct by using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
td.click(function(i, j, event){
  console.log(i, j);
}.bind(td, i, j));
```

**Note** This `.bind` solution requires ECMAScript 5, so if you want to support older browsers, please look into [es5-shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)

---

See this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/naomi/JS6q7/)

Comment: `function hello() { return 'hi'; }`

Comment: @naomik $scope.on("hi", function(){alert("LOL. How are you today?")});

Comment: @naomik You are so sweet :D

Comment: I added a demo too :)

Answer (score 0):

Other option can be storing data within the elements.

```
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
      var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
      for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) 
      {
          var td = $('<td></td>');
          this.data("position",{row:i, column:j});

          td.click(function() 
          {
            var position = this.data("position");
            alert(position.row + ' ' + position.column);  // here I want to access to CURRENT i, j variables
          })

          td.appendTo(tr);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would store the indexes as attributes and add a single click handler to the table :

```
var tableHtml = '';

for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
    tableHtml += '<tr>';

    for (var j=0; j<5; j++) {
        tableHtml += '<td data-i="' + i + '" data-j="' + j + '"></td>';
    }

    tableHtml += '</tr>';
}

$('table').append(tableHtml).on('click', 'td', function(ev) {
    var i = this.getAttribute('data-i'),
        j = this.getAttribute('data-j');
});
```

Comment: nice idea, poor implementation (IMHO).  jQuery provides perfectly good methods to directly access per-element data, and there's no need for the data to ever appear in the serialised HTML representation.

Comment: True.
I would happily use html5's dataset but it's not available in IE8-, that's why jQuery uses custom data(), for the sake of retro-compatiblity.
Data-attributes are perfectly standard and integrated with HTML5's dataset.
jQuery's data() can leave some dirt when deleting elements. Or it used to... Maybe not anymore ?

Comment: The only association between HTML5 `data-XXX` attributes and jQuery's `.data()` is that the initial values of the former get copied into the latter.  Apart from that there's no linkage.

Comment: Not what I mean : dataset is not available in older browsers so jQuery uses it's own custom storage (which we access through data()) to provide a similar feature to every browser.

Comment: I'm kind of a use-standard-native-methods maniac sometimes ;)