# Is there an NPM Module for PDF metadata?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, npm

I'm looking for an `npm` module, that I can use to edit the metatags like *Author* and *Title* of PDF files.

Alternatively, an open-license JavaScript library would also be okay.

There's a program called [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/), which would be suitable if it was an `npm` module.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945445/how-to-get-pdf-title-using-pdf-js

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: @Sumeet that doesn't seem to answer my question

Comment: @TGrif Well, I've been searching for an appropriate library for a few days, but I can't find one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tested this package but [node-exiftool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-exiftool) seems to provide pdf metadata edition.

Another possibility is to write your own module with use of *pdftk* (if available) and child_process.
Maybe I will try to make one myself.

Answer (score 2):

Can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib

```js
import { PDFDocument } from 'pdf-lib';
const arrayBuffer = await readFile(file);
const pdf = await PDFDocument.load(arrayBuffer);
const pageCount = pdf.getPagesCount();
```

You have following fucntions to get the meta data from the PDF file.
Ref: https://pdf-lib.js.org/docs/api/classes/pdfdocument

```
getAuthor
getCreationDate
getCreator
getForm
getKeywords
getModificationDate
getPage
getPageCount
getPageIndices
getPages
getProducer
getSubject
getTitle
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install the [`exiftool`](https://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) command line utility to edit the metadata of PDFs:

```
sudo apt install libimage-exiftool-perl
```

Then you can use the Node.js [`child_process.exec()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) function to call the command line utility from your program:

```
'use strict';

const exec = require('util').promisify(require('child_process').exec);

const execute = async command => {
  const {stdout, stderr} = await exec(command);

  console.log((stderr || stdout).trim());
};

(async () => {
  await execute('exiftool -title="Example PDF" -author="John Doe" /var/www/example.com/public_html/example.pdf');
})();
```

Comment: Thank you, however I think node-exiftool, as suggested in @TGrif's answer, which wraps exiftool is much more convenient.