# Can Electron's printtopdf() tag the resulting document with the app's name as "content creator"?

Tags: electron, pdf-generation

When creating a pdf document (the primary purpose of the app), it will currently list "Chromium" as the content creator in MacOS's finder. This string's also evident in the pdf binary itself.

Is there a way to change this to a custom value from within the Electron API? The documentation for printtopdf() says nothing about this.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentsprinttopdfoptions-callback) doesn't seem to mention anything useful indeed. This may not have anything to do with Electron itself.

I've *printed-to-pdf* this very page:

[image]

Then as you can see "Chrome" is the *content creator* of this document. (In Electron this would be "Chromium" as you noticed.)

[image]

Your best bet might be to change the PDF metadata after the file has been saved on the file system. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41369213/1244884).

Comment: Not really the answer I was hoping for, but it seems like you're right. Thank you.